# What is the glowing orb that Star Lord is holding when he enters the temple?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

What is the orb Star Lord is holding here?

[image: Star Lord holding the orb]

It acts as a light source, and later in the scene he sets it on the ground and kicks it towards the two Saharan soldiers, who appear to disintegrate.

Any idea what it is?

Comment: When I read the title, I thought you meant the orb containing the Infinity Gem. I was like "How the hell did he miss what that was?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Marvel's own site refers to this as Star Lord's "[Plasma Ball](http://marvel.com/images/982654#0-982654)".

[image: plasma ball]

Unfortunately, they don't provide any real specifics about it.

Comment: I've been googling around and haven't found anything except that picture. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Its basically a space Oil Lamp/Lantern.

[image]

Instead of oil, it uses plasma to create light, and works like a molotov cocktail when used as a weapon or distraction. Like real oil lamps can, and have been used in many movies (none of which I can find at the moment).

Comment: Could you tell us where this information is from please?

Comment: This sounds like pure guesswork. Do you have a source on this or any reason to believe that's what's happening with the alleged plasma content?

Comment: @hydrothermal you mean besides the way it acts on screen? As phantom answer shows, it's called a plasma ball.

Comment: @cde Marvel's name for it might be more a reference to classic "[plasma globes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_globe)" than the device's in-universe functioning. Either way, I don't think there's anything in [the scene](http://youtu.be/IAC7Ztu1Hao?t=46s) that really suggests the guards are being dissolved by the plasma inside the orb exploding like a Molotov cocktail.